# Отладка NodeJS кода. Код не прошел unite тест

Tags: javascript, node.js

Задача на NodeJS: 
Написать функцию которая принимает в себя число n, а возвращает спиральную матрицу размером nxn елементов где в центре nˆ2. 
С этой задачей я справился

```
function fillSpiralMatrix(n) {
const result = []
const p = Math.floor(n / 2)
let i = 1
for (let k = 1; k <= p; k++) {
    for (let j = k - 1; j < n - k + 1; j++) {
        result[k - 1] = result[k - 1] || []
        result[k - 1][j] = i++;
    }
    for (let j = k; j < n - k + 1; j++) {
        result[j] = result[j] || []
        result[j][n - k] = i++
    }
    for (let j = n - k - 1; j >= k - 1; j--) {
        result[n - k] = result[n - k] || []
        result[n - k][j]= i++
    }
    for (let j = n - k - 1; j>= k; j--) {
        result[j] = result[j] || []
        result[j][k - 1] = i++
    }
}
if (n % 2 == 1) {
    result[p] = result[p] || []
    result[p][p] = n * n
}
console.log(result)
return result;
}

// export default fillSpiralMatrix; 
let array = fillSpiralMatrix(4)
module.exports = fillSpiralMatrix
```

Вот результаты работы кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но unite тестирование он не прошел. Вот результат тестирования:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже пробовал закоментировать строку

`module.exports = fillSpiralMatrix;`

И раскоментировать строку

```
export default fillSpiralMatrix;
```

Но ничего не помогает. 
Вот ссылка на github репозиторий - https://github.com/Quinlys/-Igor-Yakymiv--tasks

Задача в папке "Task-1", юнит тесты в папке "Test". Пожалуйста помогите разобратся в чем проблема.

Comment: Может, `module.exports = {fillSpiralMatrix: fillSpiralMatrix};`?

Comment: Нет, код все так же работает.  Unite тест не прошел